# accepting case-insensitive input and printing them out correctly

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf

Hi guys I wrote a better and improved hangman game that accepts lowercase input and uppercase input.
The only problem that I have is that for example if the String looks like this "tnt" it prints out every character big in the console. I am trying to make it print out the exact same string.
So if I input big 'T' then it should accept it and output small 't'.

Could someone help me?

Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_WORD 100

int get_word(char *word, int size) {
    fgets(word, size, stdin);
    int len = strlen(word);
    if (len && word[len - 1] == '\n')
        word[--len] = '\0';
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        if (isalpha(word[i]))
            word[i] = toupper(word[i]);
        else
            return -1;
    return len;
}

void create_output(char *output, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        output[i] = '_';
    output[len] = '\0';
}

void print_output(const char *output, const char *alpha, int tries) {
    printf("(%d)  ", tries);
    for (int i = 0; output[i]; ++i)
        printf("%c ", output[i]);
    printf("  %s\n", alpha);
}

bool play_game(const char *word, int len) {
    char alpha[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char output[MAX_WORD];
    create_output(output, len);
    int tries = 0, guessed = 0;
    while (tries < len && guessed < len) {  // using word length for number of tries (?!)
        print_output(output, alpha, tries);
        printf("Guess: ");
        char guess;
        scanf(" %c", &guess);
        guess = toupper(guess);
        if (alpha[guess - 'A'] != ' ') {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
                if (word[i] == guess && output[i] == '_') {
                    output[i] = word[i];
                    ++guessed;
                }
            alpha[guess - 'A'] = ' ';
            ++tries;
        }
    }
    print_output(output, alpha, tries);
    return guessed == len;
}

int main() {
    printf("Enter word to guess: ");
    char word[MAX_WORD];
    int len = get_word(word, sizeof word);
    if (len == -1) {
        printf("The word cannot contain spaces.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (play_game(word, len))
        printf("You win!\n");
    else
        printf("You lose.\nThe word was %s.\n", word);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a `tolower` function that works in much the same way as `toupper` (with one obvious difference).

Comment: Aside: you don't need to check with `isalpha` before calling `toupper`, which is safe.

Comment: It's not mandatory, put you should take the habit of using {} in your for/if/... even if there is only one statement following it. Especially in `for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) \n if (isalpha(word[i]))``, to begin with. The code is both easier to read and safer if ever changed later

Comment: @AdrianMole I know but I can't figure out where to add it in my code. I know it's simple but I am really stuck